# Is there a way to disable default formtastic layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webforms, formtastic

For one specific case I would like to render the form as a part of  (for in-place editing). Is there a way in formtastic to disable the layout generated by .inputs / .buttons? Instead a

```
<fieldset> <ol> <li>
```

i would like simply to wrap the fields in the

```
<td>
```

Is there a build-in way or any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in way (yet) in Formtastic to change the mark-up. Either use CSS to tweak the ample mark-up hooks in place, or ditch Formtastic for this form and code your own way (like we used to).

Comment: I found a fork of formtastic with this kind of functionality, but in the end I think theres absolutely no need to use it. Doing one or two form is standard way doesn't hurt that much anyway. :-)

Comment: @justin-french does recent versions of Formtastic still lack mentioned functionality?

Comment: @gmile Formtastic 2 (unreleased master branch on Github) has the ground work in place for customising the markup by overriding small methods in the code. The intent was to allow for small tweaks, but I supposed it could ambitiously be used to use tables instead of lists or divs or whatever. What you're asking for is obviously ridiculously complex.

Comment: I @gmile I posted a quick introduction to the new customisable inputs on my blog. Beyond that, you'd have to go code diving. http://justinfrench.com/notebook/formtastic-2-preview-custom-inputs

Comment: Perhaps best would be to remove all formatting not related to the actual control.  No LI, or TD.. Leave those to us to add, it could be a flag to just turn it off.

Comment: @JustinFrench You could also quite quickly allow the user to specify the tag... Use LI as the default, but have another parameter that allows one to override the tag. Not sure why that's complex. right around line 302 input_helper.rb  (options[:wrapper] || :li)

Comment: @JustinFrench Huge fan of your work! Just wanted to say that. Also wanted to say that I agree with this thread. I'm kinda orthodox to bootstrap, and would love to have both worlds. Either way, thanks for your awesome contributions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not yet supported, however you can use forked formtastic version:
https://github.com/linoj/formtastic

More details at:
http://www.vaporbase.com/postings/Replaceable_render_engines_for_Formtastic

Read on the formtastic forum that it might be even merge to origin someday.

Answer (score 1):

In rails you can overrite the functions that define the tags that are used to render elements:

config/initializers/formtastic_foundation.rb:

```
# change required fields advice tag (abbr -> span)
Formtastic::FormBuilder.required_string =
proc { Formtastic::Util.html_safe(%{<span title="#{Formtastic::I18n.t(:required)}">*</span>}) }

module Formtastic
  module Helpers
    # change field wrapper (ol -> div)
    module FieldsetWrapper
      protected
      def field_set_and_list_wrapping(*args, &block) #:nodoc:
        contents = args.last.is_a?(::Hash) ? '' : args.pop.flatten
        html_options = args.extract_options!

        if block_given?
          contents = if template.respond_to?(:is_haml?) && template.is_haml?
          template.capture_haml(&block)
          else
            template.capture(&block)
          end
        end

        contents = contents.join if contents.respond_to?(:join)

        legend = field_set_legend(html_options)
          fieldset = template.content_tag(:fieldset,
          Formtastic::Util.html_safe(legend) << template.content_tag(:div, Formtastic::Util.html_safe(contents)),
          html_options.except(:builder, :parent, :name)
        )

        fieldset
      end
    end
  end

  module Inputs
    module Base
      # change input wrapper tag (li.default_clases -> div.large-12.columns inside div.row)
      module Wrapping
        def input_wrapping(&block)
          def super_wrapper_html_options
            {:class => 'row'}
          end

          new_class = [wrapper_html_options[:class], "large-12 columns"].compact.join(" ")

          template.content_tag(:div,
            template.content_tag(:div,
              [template.capture(&block), error_html, hint_html].join("\n").html_safe,
              wrapper_html_options.merge(:class => new_class)),
            super_wrapper_html_options)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I use this code to integrate Formtastic 3 with Foundation 5.4.5

Answer (score -2):

I wrapped my call to the formtastic bit (in my haml file) in a string and then subbed out the

```
= "#{f.input ...}".gsub('<li class=', '<fart class=').html_safe #remove the li to align this input with the other text in the table.
```

It's a might bit easier than re-writing the form without formtastic, and it worked perfectly.

Admittedly it's a not an ideal solution.  For a one off though... I can live with it.

Comment: you could use <td> instead of <fart>.  Though who could argue with the fact that farts are much funnier than td.